# How can you use the Twitter search API from an app hosted in another cloud?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, apex-code

This is a question regarding the undocumented limits that Twitter will impose for overusing their search API. This app resides on Force.com and therefore shares physical IP addresses with potentially large numbers of users in a multi-tenant architecture.

Key [search api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) concerns documented in [Using the Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search):

- Search does not support authentication meaning all queries are made
  anonymously.
- ... the rate limit is measured against the **requesting client IP**
- To prevent abuse the rate limit for Search is *not* published

So how do I write an application that does **not** share API call limits with thousands of other apps hosted on the same IP address?

Comment: Doing further research on this and lots of testing, it appears that the search API limits per IP address may be fairly generous. I can fire off queries, one after the other, without hitting a limit. But I'm still naturally concerned about publishing an application based on limits that I can't know or produce any guidelines on for the end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to proxy search requests through a dedicated IP. A cheap VPS or AWS micro instance wouldn't cost much.

Comment: Thanks abraham. I'm architecting a solution that avoids the search API and uses authentication (giving 350 calls per hour per authenticated user). But your suggestion sounds like the best path for search API.